# htaccess remove specific get parameter from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-authentication

I'm using Google OAuth to connect to the dashboard, the problem is that when the `GET` `&scope` parameter of the callback contains a URL like "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", the host return an Error 403.

So after many researches the only solution I found is to remove **scope** from the url.

I want to change the callback url from this:

```
https://msite.com/?code=xxx&scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

To this

```
https://msite.com/?code=xxx&scope=true
```

Here is my basic htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?code=([^&]+)&scope=email.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?code=%1&scope=true [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect your URLs from

```
/?code=Sometext&scope=emailSometext
```

To

```
/?code=Sometext&scope=true
```